# UnicodeEncodeError with Tweepy when trying to save Stream of Tweets as json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, tweepy

So I am trying to save the Tweets I am streaming through Tweepy on Python. I am using this code -->

```
class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
def on_status(self, status):
    print (status.text)

def on_data(self, data):
    json_data = json.loads(data)
    file.write(str(json_data))

def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True


sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=['#GDPR'])
```

So when I run the code, this what the console throws out -->

```
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=['GDPR'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-20-564026ea611c>", line 2, in <module>
sapi.filter(track=['GDPR'])

File "/Users/Sweeties/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
self._start(async)

File "/Users/Sweeties/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
self._run()

File "/Users/Sweeties/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
raise exception

File "/Users/Sweeties/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 263, in _run
self._read_loop(resp)

File "/Users/Sweeties/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 324, in _read_loop
self._data(next_status_obj)

File "/Users/Sweeties/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 297, in _data
if self.listener.on_data(data) is False:

File "<ipython-input-16-674fb26e0cb4>", line 7, in on_data
file.write(str(json_data))

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 133-134: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried googling the answer, but I was not able to find anything related to this particular problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have non-ascii characters that's not supported by Python 2 str. Just get rid of the str() in your file.write(...)

Comment: I changed it to this one:

        def on_data(self, data):
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        file.write(json_data)

And I got this as a result -->

      TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict

Comment: You need to serialize the dict. It seems that it's json. Then use file.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False))